# WHERE not working when it should be?

Tags: php, mysql, database, where-clause

before I start I have looked over the answers related but I cannot figure this out

Hello, I am trying to fetch the values with just the data from formtype = 'Question1'
the value is in the database under column formtype as Question1, it is a radio option value which is one of 3 values that I use to redirect information over to one page, so I have to do this on each page to get that specific information. My question is, why is it not selecting the values that contain Question1? it doesn't grab anything at all, but if I get rid of WHERE it grabs all the information just fine(which i only wanna grab the one containing Question1). Why is this? it isnt showing any errors with SELECT so I don't know what I did wrong.

I am connected to the database

```
<?php $db_name = 'submissions';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_host = 'localhost';
mysql_connect("localhost", $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("submissions") or die(mysql_error());
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT actual_quote,poster,formtype FROM data WHERE formtype = 'Question1'");   
$info = mysql_fetch_array($query1); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
echo ' 
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
<div class="logo-logo"><h2>Questions.</h2>
<div class="checkboxes">'.$info['formtype'].'
</div>

</div>
<div class="top-submit">
&#8220'. $info["actual_quote"] . '&#8221;
</div>
<div class="poster">- '. $info["poster"].'
<div class = "like">
<a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style =     "color:green;">Like</a>
<p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
</div>
<div class = "dislike">
<a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right;   color:red;">Dislike</a>
<p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- use select to get the items to stay on the page-->

</div>
</div>
</div>
';
}

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: First correct your connection like mysql_select_db("submissions",$con_object)

Comment: Not to do with your error but please look into MySQLi or PDO for database handling as mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: What does phpMyAdmin show when you execute that query?

Comment: Can you put the error here... Why yo are putting $info = mysql_fetch_array($query1); 2 times. 1 in while and another before while.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Also, of what type is `formtype`?

Comment: Check the value you in database and the value you are searching may be both are different some space or other issues will be their

Comment: @marsze it is a varchar

Answer (score 0):

Fix these lines:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("submissions",$link) or die(mysql_error());
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT actual_quote,poster,formtype FROM data WHERE formtype = 'Question1'",$link);   
//delete this-> $info = mysql_fetch_array($query1);   ?
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
```